# What do you do if the decryption key d is equal to 1?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cryptography

To decrypt some M, we use the fact that M $\equiv$ $(M')^d$ mod n. To find d, I did $e^{\Phi((p-1)(q-1))}$ mod ((p-1)(q-1)).

In my particular case, n = 1643, e = 223, p = 31, q = 53. Therefore, d $\equiv$ $223^{\Phi((30)(52))}$ mod 1560 $\equiv$ $223^{384}$ mod 1560.

I am getting 1 for this last step, which does not seem to be right.

Comment: Just edited my question with more detail.

Comment: $\Phi = (p-1)(q-1)$ and $d = e^{-1} \pmod{\Phi} = 223^{-1} \pmod{1560} = 7$.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not $\Phi((p-1)(q-1))$, but just $223^{1560}$?

Comment: See the details in the comment I added above for calculating $d$, we have that $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\Phi} \implies d \equiv e^{-1} \pmod{\Phi} \equiv e^{-1} \pmod{(p-1)(q-1)}$. Of course, we are also talking about modular inverses here.

Comment: Is $e^{-1}$ just $e^{\Phi(pq)}$?

Comment: $e^{-1} \equiv e^{\phi(pq)-1}\pmod{pq}$. The $-1$ on the right-hand side is important, and indeed without it, you will always erroneously get $1$ by Euler's theorem.

Comment: Didn't you mean $\pmod{\Phi}$ instead of $\pmod{p q}$?

Answer (score 2):

**Your decryption key should be 7**

$d = e^{-1}(mod1560)$

$d = 223^{-1}(mod1560)$

**Extended Euclidean Algorithm**

$1560 = 223 * 6 + 222$

$223 = 222 * 1 + 1$

$222 = 1 * 222 + 0$

**Go backward**

$1 = 223 - 1*222$

$1 = 223 - 1 (1560 - 6*223)$

$1 = 7*223 - 1 *1560$

$1 = 7*223(mod1560)$

**Therefore d=7**

To check:

$ed \equiv 1 (mod1560)$

$223*7 \equiv 1 (mod1560)$

$1561 \equiv 1(mod1560)$

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong way to compute the decryption key. If $n=pq$, then public key $(n,e)$ has the private decryption key $d$ where $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$, not $e^{\phi(\phi(n))} \pmod {\phi(n)}$, as you think.

As here $\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)  =1560$ you need to find the inverse of $223$ modulo $1560$. This is indeed $7$ as $7 \times 223 = 1561$ and can be found using the extended Euclidean algorithm.